# Splitting '12213123_mul_32432532' in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, string, http

I hav Got HTTP Request Like

```
GET /1213123_mul_32424324.html HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: .....
etc...etc...
```

I need to send the multiplication of Integers 1213123 and 32424324...
So I have created a Python ccript for this. I used the `req.find()` method to fetch integer.
but there should be a better way, like using regex.

Whats the best way to fetch integers from this request?

Comment: You have a web service for multiplying numbers? What for?

Answer (score 4):

This is a case where a regex is applicable:

```
>>> re.search(r'^GET /(\d+)_mul_(\d+)\.html', 'GET /1213123_mul_32424324.html HTTP/1.1').groups()
('1213123', '32424324')
```

Cast the values using `int()`, multiply them and do what you want with the result.

To compare, this is how you could do it with `.split()`. I don't advise using this method, unless you can be sure the request will have a `.` after the second number.

```
>>> n = 'GET /1213123_mul_32424324.html HTTP/1.1'.split()[1][1:].split('_mul_')
>>> n[1] = n[1][:n[1].index('.')]
>>> n
['1213123', '32424324']
```